# What query can I use to get the URLs with the most FB comments on a certain domain/appID?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I'm trying to display the most commented stories on a site, what query can I use to get URLs with the most Facebook comments on a certain domain or appID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Start with this as an example and work your way into getting the stream items for the appId

`fql?q=SELECT post_id, attachment.href, comments.count FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type=80 ORDER BY comments.count DESC LIMIT 500`

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/